# Create air stream from heat

Tags: fluid-dynamics, heat-engine

We know that heating the air inside a bounded box raises its pressure. And if there is a hole in the box, then air flows out until the pressure inside and outside balances. So in this case we would have a temporal air stream.

But my question is, is it possible to have some passive design that permanent heat injection into the structure create permanent air flows through it? I mean from one side air flows in (somehow), heat rise its temperature and then air flows out from other side?
So we could have something like a jet engine, without using flammable fuel.
The efficiency and power is not really matter, but I want to know is this really possible in theory or practice?

If there is any topics around this question, I would be glad to be if you provide references.

Comment: Be careful using the word "turbulence" with fluid dynamics, it has a very precise meaning that isn't what the lay-person would use. So the phrase "temporal turbulence" doesn't really have a technical meaning -- what are you trying to describe? Also -- if you don't want to use a flammable fuel, how do you propose heating the gas you plan on using? Jet engines work by 2 principles -- generate a whole lot of compression upstream, and release a whole lot of heat (to expand gases) downstream to perform work. Are you thinking about something like an electrically heated jet engine?

Comment: Ok, so the turbulence may not be the right word, I mean an stream of air, from one side in and another side out. Then I should change this word I suppose?!

When I say i don't want to use a flammable fuel, I mean a passive structure, like a room that heats comes from point (no matter how) heats air, and air flows up, and a circulation happens. I don't want to use pressure from burning the gas. 

Here I want to know if is it possible to have a structure like a cylinder that convert heat to continuous air stream?

Comment: I have heard of research into jet engines using heating coils rather than injected fuel. The problem is that they would overheat and melt, and would take a HUGE amount of energy.

Comment: I should point out that the burning of fuel is to heat the air. Any method of heating would work, but so far the burning of hydrocarbons is the most efficient.

Comment: @CoilKid, thanks, it seems to be what I want, could you explain more? as I mentioned here, it's not matter how thrust can it make, or how efficient it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any form of heat will work, but there also needs to be a way to raise the pressure, such as ram air or a compressor.

If you don't have a compressor, the air will flow out both ends, for zero thrust.

A very simple way to do this is with a propane torch.
The gas is under pressure in the bottle.
Then it is allowed to escape into the burner at a slightly higher pressure than atmospheric.
Then it burns, which fills it with heat, which greatly expands the gas.

Now you have a large volume of gas, at the same pressure as it came into the burner, so it rushes out with more momentum than it came in with, and that's the definition of thrust.

Answer (score 0):

In a jet engine, we burn hydrocarbons (jet fuel) which heat the air. When air (or any gas) is heated, the volume changes. We can calculate the change in volume by using [Charles' law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles%27s_law). $$\frac{T_1}{V_1}=\frac{T_2}{V_2}$$
When the air gets hot it expands and is forced out the back of the engine, producing thrust.

All you need is something to heat the air. We burn hydrocarbons because of the tremendous chemical energy released when they combust. If [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octane) is correct, 1 mol of octane (the main component in gasoline) will release 5330 kJ of energy when combusted.

In order to match the thrust of an octane driven jet engine, you would have to calculate how many mols of octane are being combusted in a certain time frame (say 1 second) and match that energy output with some other heat source.

For example: If you wanted to make an electric jet engine with the same thrust as one that used 1 mol of octane per second (1 mol $C_8H_{18}$/second), you would have to make your electric engine have an energy output of 5330 kJ/second.

While the energies released in the example seem acceptable, a real jet engine guzzles *much* more than 1 mol of octane per second, and therefore would require much more energy to match.

Comment: The pressure change isn't all there is to it -- if you took a tube open on both ends and heated it, you would get flow outwards until the inner pressure was equal to the outer pressure and then it would stop. If there is to be a continuous stream produced, work must be extracted from the outgoing air (turbine) and used to compress air at the inlet to cause it to flow into the tube (the compressor). Otherwise you'll just get a temporary movement of air and then nothing.

Comment: Unless said device was vertical in a gravity field (like a candle inside a tube) where buoyancy would create the convection needed to drive the inflow/outflow process.

Comment: @CoilKid, So if I got it right, it's not matter what heats the air, and how it expanded during burning, we could make air flow without hydrocarbons based on the principle of jet engines using any heat generator, e.g. a radiator?!

Comment: WOW @tpg2114 the compressor!! that is the one which make airflow continuous?! what about gravity? Could you explain more?

Comment: @tpg2114 Yes, that's true. Jet engines do use compressors. I didn't think it would be relevant to the question, as it seemed to be about heat sources.

Comment: @2i3r As tpg2114 mentioned, jet engines do have compressors. Usually, it's the first part you see when you look into a jet engine, and it goes back a ways. The compressor is used to pull/push fresh air through the heating chamber, and to keep the heated air from exiting out the front of the engine. I say "usually" because there are cases in which the engine does not have a compressor. To read more about those types of engines, look at the Wikipedia link on ramjets in my next comment.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramjet. You also might be interested in scramjets which are related to ramjets -  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scramjet